# Find least recently used mysql table index

Tags: mysql, index, innodb, database-tuning

I am cleaning up duplicate indices from (innodb)tables in a mysql database. The database has about 50 tables.

While I can check for duplicate keys using pt-duplicate-key-checker, I was wondering if there is a tool that could help me find out least recently used indices from all the tables.

For eg. , if table "A" has three indices defined "index_1", "index_2" and "index_3", and out of them "index_3" is used least frequently , assume its used every 1/10000 queries made on the table, then the output of the script or tool should be "index_3".

Is there a good way or a tool that could help me run this analysis on the database?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Starting with MySQL 5.6, the `performance_schema` instruments Table I/O, and computes aggregated statistics by `table`, and by `index`.

See table `performance_schema.table_io_waits_summary_by_index_usage`:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/table-waits-summary-tables.html#table-io-waits-summary-by-index-usage-table

Finding the least *recently* used index involves time and timestamps.

The performance schema measure counting I/O against an index.  It can be used to find the least *often* used index, which in practice should be pretty close.

Full example here:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c129c/4

Comment: Isn't this unhelpful when your entire DB fits into memory, so there'd be no IO after long enough?

Comment: @aehike,Table I/O is measured at the sql layer / storage engine interface. File I/O is below, at the storage engine / File system interface. Even if the entire DB is in RAM, and the file system is never hit, the MySQL server will still call the storage engine (innodb, etc) for rows, and table I/O will be counted here.